# How to ping from master to minion in kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

how to connect from master to minion, i have tried Internal IP and public IP but it shows failure. Ping gives 100% packet loss.

Master and minions both are created aws instances, and through `fleetctl` i can see list of minions on master machine.

Used this example :https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/guestbook

Comment: Perhaps your firewall rules need adjusting?

Comment: @lavalamp thanks changed Security group settings and it worked

Answer (score 0):

[Re-posting lavalamp's comment above so that this question is answered]:

It looks like you need to adjust your firewall to allow communication from the master to the nodes.